# Задать последовательность выполнения функций (дождаться завершения одной, затем вызвать другую)

Tags: javascript, php

Сделал чат, заморочился с обновлением окна чата без перезагрузки страницы. Теперь, при добавлении новой записи в чат, нужно промотать окно в самый низ, к добавленной записи. Сделал так:

```
function show_chat(btn) {
$("#div_comments").load("chat.php", $(btn).closest("form").serialize());// отрисовать чат
    document.getElementById('div_comments').scrollTop = 9999;   // промотать вниз
}
```

Скролл срабатывает, но, такое впечатление, что вызывается прежде, чем добавится новая запись, встаёт на предпоследнюю. Как дождаться завершения отрисовки, прежде чем вызывать скролл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function show_chat(btn) {
  $("#div_comments").load("chat.php", $(btn).closest("form").serialize(), function() {
    document.getElementById('div_comments').scrollTop = 9999;
  });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

Comment: как всё просто ) Спасибо, работает.